# python, pandas, I have data like <16 * MonthEnds>, how to compare it to an integer?

Tags: python, pandas

my data looks like this:

```
<16 * MonthEnds>
<19 * MonthEnds>
<23 * MonthEnds>
<12 * MonthEnds>
<24 * MonthEnds>
<13 * MonthEnds>
```

and i want to do something like:

```
if Duration<12:
    do something
```

but i can't find away to compare the duration with an integer

i always get an error

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.MonthEnd' and 'int'
```

Comment: What should the data even mean? How is it related to a duration?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `MonthEnds` offset to integer:

```
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)

# OR

df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].map(lambda x: getattr(x, 'n')) < 12
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Duration
0        16
1        19
2        23
3        12
4        24
5        13
```

Comment: Why convert to string if you can get the `int` directly? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55979153/7483211

Comment: Are you sure what are you saying? Show me it works with `df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration': [pd.offsets.MonthEnd(16)]})`. To get the `dt` accessor, you need to have a PeriodIndex or a DatetimeIndex.

Comment: @richardec. Don't be in a hurry to close the post before testing :)

Comment: are you saying the linked question is in fact a different one? If so, what's the difference? Or are the answers given there wrong? It'd help if repro data was in the question here itself.

Comment: I think the answer for Pandas 0.24 doesn't work anymore. I'm agree for reproducible data!